# Memory leak issue with recursively defined list

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks

## Problem Context

I'm currently trying to create a little Haskell EDSL to describe Electronic Circuits and simulate them. I've heard of Lava but didn't really read about it as I wanted to go for the "full adventure". I ended up with a typeclass `Bit` representing anything you can make logical operations on and using lists to represent time (the n-th element being the value at the n-th cycle).

## Problem itself

My registers are implemented as `reg input = ground : input` where ground is a `Bit b => b` representing the logical false. This implementation is pretty effective as far as I don't loop a register on itself. Indeed, when writing something like `alternate = not <$> (reg alternate)` I end up building huge thunks of `not . not . not ... . not $ ground` whereas something like

```
iterate' f x = x `seq` x : (iterate' f (f x))
alternate = iterate' not ground
```

would have been way more efficient. Though, this won't work for a register that isn't part of a loop, and I'd like not to separate syntax for 1) looped register 2) not looped register.

I'm kind of stuck there, but have a feeling that this is quite a common problem and someone may hence have a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you like to try a monadic approach, you might want to take a look at Levent Erkök's dissertation [Value Recursion in Monadic Computations](http://digitalcommons.ohsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1163&context=etd) (Chapter 1.2) and the [MonadFix package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Fix.html).

Coincidentally, Erkök motivates his research by showing a Monadic solution for circuit description and interpretation. As he shows, using a Monad, a circuit description does not have to be changed if you require a different behavior (for example simply drawing instead of analysing a circuit). This might be also very useful, depending on how far you want to go with your implementation.

To give you a taste for the solution, from his dissertation:

```
halfAdd :: Circuit m => Sig Bool -> Sig Bool -> m (Sig Bool, Sig Bool)

halfAdd s1 s2 = do  
    sum <- xor s1 s2
    carry <- and s1 s2
    return (sum, carry)
```

Which looks pretty neat (see Chapter 1.2 for the full details), where **>>=** and **return** define your circuit model **m**, Sig is a list of values and Circuit a typeclass with generic operations like **xor**, **and**, ... .

More importantly, he discusses recursions (feedback loops) in Monads and points out that you do not want to loop over the circuit elements, possibly replicating them (and creating thunks as in your case) but over the actual signal values, hence the need for Value Recursion.

Thus, a not gate with a feedback loop would look like:

```
toggle sig = mdo
    inp <- inv out
    out <- delay "False" False inp -- Used to define the initial signal value on the wire
    return out
```

Note the use of the **mdo**, instead of do, which allows (mutual) recursive definitions. (You have to enable the RecursiveDo extension to get support for mdo).

Under the hood, this will be translated into

```
toggle sig = do
    mfix (\out -> do
        inp <- inv out
        out' <- delay "False" False inp
        return out')
```

(see also https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/MonadFix for more information on notation).

Note that this solution, together with a definition for mfix (for your particular circuit model / monad) will not generate any intermediary gates. 
You can find all the design and implementation details in the dissertation, plus more material on interesting laws.

Maybe this is of some help to you.

Edit: Provided a more detailed answer.

Comment: Actually, I've already base my approach on something similar (even using Arrows to describe my circuit !) but my problem here is more related to the "use lists to represent the time" than the monadic recursion itself (even if this point may become problematic once).

Comment: I see. Would you like to share your code? I might learn a thing or two and maybe someone else can provide better advice (I have never used arrows myself, but who knows maybe I'll come up with something).